# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.searchbox.action.Action.getURI()Ljava/lang/String

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, kubernetes, elasticsearch-jest

I am getting error while building my spring boot application. I am using ES and error comes while jestClient invokes execute method.
Error:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.searchbox.action.Action.getURI()Ljava/lang/String;

Error comes from the execute method of jestHttpClient.class

```
public <T extends JestResult> T execute(Action<T> clientRequest, RequestConfig requestConfig) throws IOException {
    HttpUriRequest request = this.prepareRequest(clientRequest, requestConfig);
    CloseableHttpResponse response = null;

    JestResult var5;
    try {
        response = this.executeRequest(request);
        var5 = this.deserializeResponse(response, request, clientRequest);
    } catch (HttpHostConnectException var14) {
        throw new CouldNotConnectException(var14.getHost().toURI(), var14);
    } finally {
        if (response != null) {
            try {
                response.close();
            } catch (IOException var13) {
                log.error("Exception occurred while closing response stream.", var13);
            }
        }

    }

    return var5;
```

}

Comment: Can you provide the version of your dependency ( searchbox-io / Jets)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error that happens when you compile a different version of the class that its being refered in the code. This can happen due you have the dependency imported twice.

For example you can manually import a dependency that contains `io.searchbox.action.Action` but `io.searchbox.action.Action` is also imported in a dependency inside another dependency whith another version.

Just take care about the version you are compiling because in Jest newest versions getURL is as follows

```
String getURI(ElasticsearchVersion elasticsearchVersion);
```

But on in 5.3.4 is as follows

```
String getURI();
```